# (Project Euler #3) Trying to replicate a solution in Python to C++, going horribly wrong, not sure how

Tags: python, c++

**EDIT: Solved! Simple mistake, accidentally left the int values at just int which couldn't hold that big of a number. Thanks for the help!**

I already completed the Project Euler third problem:

"The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?"?

In Python with this code (that works):

```
def main():
    num = 600851475143 # You can replace this number with any number you want to find the largest prime to
    x = 2
    while x * x < num: 
        while num % x == 0:
            num = num / x #Divide number by generated number (X) to get the prime number.
        x = x + 1 # Continue in formula searching for largest prime
    print num #Prints largest prime of the assigned number (600851475143)
main()
```

and that worked fine. However, when I tried replacating said code into C++ with this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int num = 600851475143;
    int x = 2;
    while (x*x < num)
    {
        while (num % x == 0)
        {
            num /= x;
        }
        x = x++;
    }
    std::cout << num;

    char z;
    std::cin >> z;
    return 0;
}
```

I always get the output "-443946297" instead of the correct and very different output I was expecting, "6857"

Can anyone help explain how I am getting such an extremely crazy answer from essentially the same code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

600851475143 is probably too large to fit in an `int`, leading to overflow. Try changing the type to `long long`. (You should probably change `x` to `long long` too, although it *might* not matter in this case.)

Comment: Bahaha, I feel pretty stupid now. Thanks for the help, that was it! :)